# Using nested If Statements in Java and ignoring conditions where applicable

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to Java, so apologies if this is a simple fix...

I have written a short script for a VIP lounge which implements nested if statements. The conditions are that a customer must be aged >=18 and have a VIP pass to enter, or if the customer is aged >=50 they can enter without a VIP pass. The program works fine, but if the customer enters their age as 50+, they are still being asked if they have a VIP pass, although this question is not needed if they are over 50. I have tried using a else if statement but to no avail.

Please advise. The source code follows...

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("The VIP Lounge");       
    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
    int age = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    
    if (age >= 18) {
        System.out.print("Do you have a VIP pass? yes/no: ");       
        String vipPassReply = keyboardInput.next();
        
        if (vipPassReply.equals("yes") || age >= 50) {
            // over 50's can enter the VIP lounge without a pass
            System.out.println("Thanks. Go on in.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you must either be over 50, or have a VIP pass to enter.");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you must be over 18.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Well, 50 is greater than 18. So if they enter their age as 50, the `age >= 18` condition is true. And what happens immediately after checking that condition, if it happens to be true? They are asked if they have a VIP pass. Or in other words, the order in which you've set your conditional statements does not reflect the requirements of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redone your code. Incase of anything feel free to ask. This Works with all Test Cases

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The VIP Lounge");
    System.out.print("Enter your age: ");
    int age = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    

    if (age < 18) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you must be over 18.");
    } else {

        if (age < 50) {
            System.out.print("Do you have a VIP pass? yes/no: ");
            String vipPassReply = keyboardInput.next();
            if (vipPassReply.equals("yes")) {
                // over 50's can enter the VIP lounge without a pass
                System.out.println("Thanks. Go on in.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you must either be over 50, or have a VIP pass to enter.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thanks. Go on in.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! A++++++

Comment: Posting code is not enough, please explain for readers why you wrote this code and what the OP was missing in the 1st place

Answer (score 1):

Okey just implement what you want logic in your code.

So you want the user who are +18 to are allowed to pass but with a VIP permission.
But for users +50 they can pass without VIP permission.

So what you need?

You ask the user for their age. As you asked
Then check `if user is +18` (as you do)

But there before asking for VIP you need to check `if user is +50` so if that is true you can print "You can go in".
But if user user is +50 you should ask for a VIP pass (on `else`). Then if user answer was "YES" they can go in. Otherway you can print "You need a VIP pass to enter"

And on `else` when you check `if user is +18` you can print "You must be +18 to enter".

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to invert conditions: use `age < 18` instead of `age >= 18` and then check for 50-year limit to ask for VIP password if needed to prevent code duplication.

Also, if user input is expected, it could be preferable to use `equalsIgnoreCase` when checking for `"yes"` response.

```java
if (age < 18) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you must be over 18.");
}
else {
    String vipPassReply = "yes";

    if (age < 50) {
        System.out.print("Do you have a VIP pass? yes/no: ");       
        vipPassReply = keyboardInput.next();
    }
    if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(vipPassReply)) {
        System.out.println("Thanks. Go on in.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you must either be over 50, or have a VIP pass to enter.");
    }
}
```